# Is "lazy loading" feature of orm or jpa?

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I've started studying JPA for spring application.

I saw the "Spring-Data-JDBC" Project and it describes "JPA offers such features as lazy loading, caching, and dirty tracking".

Here's the question.

Are features such as lazy loading, caching, and dirty tracking existed only in JPA? not in ORM?

**About JPA what I found out:**

I've found out this answer "JPA is just a specification, not an ORM tool. JPA is a set of classes, interfaces that helps your ORM tool to map O-R according to JPA standards. You can use Hibernate, TopLink/EclipseLink etc to have JPA implemented in your application." from Quora.

But they didn't mentioned about the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA specifies lazy and eager loading. JPA implementors must implement those to be JPA compliant.

However existing implementations were used when creating the spec, so a lot of the functionality already existed and was included in the spec based on the them:

> Gavin King founded the Hibernate project. He represented JBoss on JSR
>   220, the JCP expert group charged with developing JPA. ... Sun
>   Microsystems has stated that ideas came from several frameworks,
>   including Hibernate and Java Data Objects

Comment: Is Hibernate the RI of JPA? I thought it was EclipseLink.

Comment: @Slaw you're right, not the reference implementation. I meant to say that Hibernate was used as the basis for lots of the spec. Clarified the answer.